# Toggling the menu icon

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to trigger the menu icon off when clicked, and trigger on an 'x' icon. Likewise, I need the reverse of this to happen. Trigger the 'x' icon off when clicked, and the menu icon back on.

When `nav-button-menuOpen` is clicked, the three `divs` inside go from `opacity: 1;` to `opacity: 0;` and the button fades away like it's supposed to. Then the `span` inside `nav-button-menuClose` is supposed to go from `opacity: 0;` to `opacity: 1;`. I can see the class being added in the browser, but the animation on the `span` doesn't change the opacity property.

```js
const mobileMenuOpenAndClose = () => {
    const menuOpenButton = document.querySelector('.nav-button-menuOpen');
    const menuCloseButton= document.querySelector('.nav-button-menuClose');
    const navMobileMenu = document.querySelector('.nav-mobileMenu');
    const navMobileMenuLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-mobileMenu-links');

    menuOpenButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
      console.log('menuButtonOpen clicked');
      menuOpenButton.classList.toggle('nav-button-toggle');
      menuCloseButton.classList.toggle('nav-button-toggle');
    });

    menuCloseButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
      console.log('menuButtonClose clicked')
      menuCloseButton.classList.toggle('nav-button-toggle');
      menuOpenButton.classList.toggle('nav-button-toggle');
    });
};

mobileMenuOpenAndClose();
```

```css
/* Hamburger Menu */
nav .nav-button-menuOpen {
  justify-self: end;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 1;
}
nav .nav-button-menuOpen div {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  height: 3px;
  margin: 5px 0;
  background-color: var(--color-black);
  transition: all;
}
nav .nav-button-menuClose {
  justify-self: end;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0;
}
nav .nav-button-menuClose span {
  color: var(--color-black);
  font-size: 1rem;
  transition: all;
}
nav .nav-button-toggle .menuOpen-line  {
  opacity: 0;
}
nav .nav-button-toggle .nav-button-menuClose { 
    opacity: 1; 
}
```

```html
<nav>
<div class="nav-button-menuOpen">
  <div class="menuOpen-line"></div>
  <div class="menuOpen-line"></div>
  <div class="menuOpen-line"></div>
</div>
<div class="nav-button-menuClose">
  <span>x</span>
</div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing the css with the space in the middle like this: `.nav-button-toggle .nav-button-menuClose` applys the style to the elements children. Write `.nav-button-toggle.nav-button-menuClose` without the space in the middle to apply it to itself.

```js
const mobileMenuOpenAndClose = () => {
    const menuOpenButton = document.querySelector('.nav-button-menuOpen');
    const menuCloseButton= document.querySelector('.nav-button-menuClose');
    const navMobileMenu = document.querySelector('.nav-mobileMenu');
    const navMobileMenuLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-mobileMenu-links');

    menuOpenButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
      console.log('menuButtonOpen clicked');
      menuOpenButton.classList.toggle('nav-button-toggle');
      menuCloseButton.classList.toggle('nav-button-toggle');
    });

    menuCloseButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
      console.log('menuButtonClose clicked')
      menuCloseButton.classList.toggle('nav-button-toggle');
      menuOpenButton.classList.toggle('nav-button-toggle');
    });
};

mobileMenuOpenAndClose();
```

```css
/* Hamburger Menu */
nav .nav-button-menuOpen {
  justify-self: end;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 1;
}
nav .nav-button-menuOpen div {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  height: 3px;
  margin: 5px 0;
  background-color: black;
  transition: all;
}
nav .nav-button-menuClose {
  justify-self: end;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0;
}
nav .nav-button-menuClose span {
  color: black;
  font-size: 1rem;
  transition: all;
}
nav .nav-button-toggle .menuOpen-line  {
  opacity: 0;
}
nav .nav-button-toggle.nav-button-menuClose { 
    opacity: 1; 
}
```

```html
<nav>
<div class="nav-button-menuOpen">
  <div class="menuOpen-line"></div>
  <div class="menuOpen-line"></div>
  <div class="menuOpen-line"></div>
</div>
<div class="nav-button-menuClose">
  <span>x</span>
</div>
</nav>
```

For the animation part I would recommand you to use the CSS @keyframes Rule (https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-keyframes.asp) instead of `transiton`. This way you can easily apply a hide class with `display: none;` to the hidden elements, and if you remove the class, the animation gets triggered.

```js
const mobileMenuOpenAndClose = () => {
    const menuOpenButton = document.querySelector('.nav-button-menuOpen');
    const menuCloseButton= document.querySelector('.nav-button-menuClose');
    const navMobileMenu = document.querySelector('.nav-mobileMenu');
    const navMobileMenuLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-mobileMenu-links');

    menuOpenButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
      console.log('menuButtonOpen clicked');
      menuOpenButton.classList.toggle('hidden');
      menuCloseButton.classList.toggle('hidden');
    });

    menuCloseButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
      console.log('menuButtonClose clicked')
      menuCloseButton.classList.toggle('hidden');
      menuOpenButton.classList.toggle('hidden');
    });
};

mobileMenuOpenAndClose();
```

```css
/* Hamburger Menu */
.nav-button-menuOpen {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  animation: fadeIn 0.2s;
}
.nav-button-menuOpen div {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  height: 3px;
  margin: 5px 0;
  background-color: black;
}
.nav-button-menuClose {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  animation: fadeIn 0.2s;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from { opacity: 0 }
  to { opacity: 100 }
}

.nav-button-menuClose span {
  color: black;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.hidden {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-button-menuOpen">
  <div class="menuOpen-line"></div>
  <div class="menuOpen-line"></div>
  <div class="menuOpen-line"></div>
</div>
<div class="nav-button-menuClose hidden">
  <span>x</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are adding `nav-button-toggle` class to the `.nav-button-menuClose` element, but in your css selector you trying apply opacity if this element's parent has `nav-button-toggle` class:

`nav .nav-button-toggle .nav-button-menuClose {` 
(basically you have an extra space between classes in this selector)

```js
const mobileMenuOpenAndClose = () => {
    const menuOpenButton = document.querySelector('.nav-button-menuOpen');
    const menuCloseButton= document.querySelector('.nav-button-menuClose');
    const navMobileMenu = document.querySelector('.nav-mobileMenu');
    const navMobileMenuLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-mobileMenu-links');

    menuOpenButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
      console.log('menuButtonOpen clicked');
      menuOpenButton.classList.toggle('nav-button-toggle');
      menuCloseButton.classList.toggle('nav-button-toggle');
    });

    menuCloseButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
      console.log('menuButtonClose clicked')
      menuCloseButton.classList.toggle('nav-button-toggle');
      menuOpenButton.classList.toggle('nav-button-toggle');
    });
};

mobileMenuOpenAndClose();
```

```css
/* Hamburger Menu */
nav .nav-button-menuOpen {
  justify-self: end;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 1;
}
nav .nav-button-menuOpen div {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  height: 3px;
  margin: 5px 0;
  background-color: var(--color-black);
  transition: all;
}
nav .nav-button-menuClose {
  justify-self: end;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0;
}
nav .nav-button-menuClose span {
  color: var(--color-black);
  font-size: 1rem;
  transition: all;
}
nav .nav-button-toggle .menuOpen-line  {
  opacity: 0;
}
nav .nav-button-toggle.nav-button-menuClose { 
  opacity: 1; 
}
```

```html
<nav>
<div class="nav-button-menuOpen">
  <div class="menuOpen-line">menu1</div>
  <div class="menuOpen-line">menu2</div>
  <div class="menuOpen-line">menu3</div>
</div>
<div class="nav-button-menuClose">
  <span>x</span>
</div>
</nav>
```

As of animation, since you are only changing opacity, there nothing else to animate as there are no other changes applied to the style between the states.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve with single **.nav-menu-toggle** element to `open` and `close` menu with single click event of `JavaScript`.

```js
document.querySelector('.nav-menu-toggle').addEventListener('click', (t) => {
    t.target.classList.toggle('active');
});
```

```css
/* Hamburger Menu */
:root{
    --color-black : #000
}
nav{
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    padding: 20px;
}
nav .nav-menu-toggle {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
}
nav .nav-menu-toggle div{
    width: 100%;
    height: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: #000;
    transition: 0.5s transform cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 1);
    pointer-events: none;
}
nav .nav-menu-toggle.active div{
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
nav .nav-menu-toggle.active div:nth-child(1){
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform-origin: 110% 9px;
}
nav .nav-menu-toggle.active div:nth-child(2){
    transform: scale(0);
}
nav .nav-menu-toggle.active div:nth-child(3){
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform-origin: 95% -4.5px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="nav-menu-toggle">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</nav>
```